# How can I define linux user for different Wordpress sites on debian nginx server

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, nginx, debian

I have some wordpress sites deployed on my debian server exposed with nginx. I want to create a linux user per site but I don't know how to configure nginx and php to use each user for each site. Now It is using default www-data but I don't like this user to have access to all sites I have. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/948311) does a really good job of showing how to do it. Nginx runs as one user, but you can have a per-site PHP pool that runs as a specific user.

Comment: @ChrisHaas It looks like what I'm looking for. I'll take a look later and try to implement it. I'll post results after try it :) thanks so much